# Postgresql Failed to start on linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-11

My PostgreSQL stopped working suddenly and I am unable to start it. (Last changes in my Linux were, I tried to install dockers).

When I run the command:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

OR

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

I get the error:

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 11 database server
* Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@11-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@11-main.service' for details.
                                                                        [fail]
```

and

```
~$ sudo service postgresql status
11/main (port 5434): down
```

There result of `systemctl` status:

```
~ $ sudo systemctl status postgresql@11-main.service
postgresql@11-main.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I have tried all the available options on SO and on other forums but neither worked for me.
What can be the issue?

**EDIT:**

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Output:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.6 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

and

```
ls -al /var/lib/pgsql
```

output:

```
ls: cannot access /var/lib/pgsql: No such file or directory
```

Then I tried

```
ls -al /var/lib/postgresql/
```

output:

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  7 postgres postgres 4096 Mar 24 13:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 90 root     root     4096 Apr  6 18:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 postgres postgres 4096 Apr  6 18:20 11
drwxr-xr-x  3 postgres postgres 4096 Feb 11  2016 9.3
drwxr-xr-x  3 postgres postgres 4096 Dec  3  2018 9.4
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 31 11:20 .aptitude
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 5898 Apr  6 18:33 .bash_history
drwx------  3 postgres postgres 4096 Feb 11  2016 .cache
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 2180 Mar 24 13:34 .psql_history
```

and

```
yum info postgresql11-server
```

```
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

**EDIT 2**

```
sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep postg et
```

output:

```
grep: et: No such file or directory
```

and

```
ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/11
```

output:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Apr  6 18:20 data
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4096 Apr  2 18:53 main
```

Comment: What is the output of: `cat /etc/os-release`, `ls -al /var/lib/pgsql` , `yum info postgresql11-server`

Comment: @pifor! I have edited the question with output.

Comment: What does `ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/11` show you?

Comment: ```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Apr  6 18:20 data
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4096 Apr  2 18:53 main
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name! please see the updated question.

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl list-unit-files | grep postg` et also the output of `ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/11` ?

Comment: see edit 2 of question.

Comment: Sorry the command should be `systemctl list-unit-files | grep postg `  . What is the output of `pg_lsclusters`.

Comment: @pifor! the result of this command is blank.

Comment: on running `pg_lsclusters` it results: `Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file`

Comment: @pifor! systemctl shows blank.

Comment: I think you should deinstall and reinstall PostgreSQL: there are too many inconsistencies.

Comment: okay, I will try it.

Comment: The `data` sub-directory should not be owned by `root` - in fact everything below `/var/lib/postgresql` should be owned by `postgres`. You could try to change ownership of all the files (below `/var/lib/postgresql`)  back to `postgres` and see if that fixes things

Comment: how can I change this permission?